# How to restrict the plugin to switch rear/back camera in android / cordova

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I am using media-capture plugin of `cordova` to capture the video only from front camera. 
when it opens the camera, there is option to switch the back or rear camera, can anyone please guide, how to disable switching to back camera. I have done following modification in plugin and re added to app, but no luck.

```
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_BACK", 0);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_BACK_CAMERA", false);
```

Comment: There is already a ready-made implementation for this available in the following link - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/pull/63 But it is supported only in iOS and needs to extended for Android. Please check out

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: yet not Gandhi.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

`intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);`

---

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html

Comment: this will just open the front camera as default, does not disable back camera